# how to delete multiple row using checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

Now i am doing crud operation in jquery datatable in that in delete operation if i click on check boxes and than if i click on delete button than all that checked rows record should be deleted from table as well as database.If anybody know solution please help.Thanks in advance
Delete button  
Check boxes  "/>
code for delete operation

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#employee_data').dataTable();
        $('#delete').click(function () {
            if ($('.chkNumber:checked').length) {
                var id = '';
                $('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
                    id += $(this).val() + " ";
                });
                alert(id);
            }
            else {
                alert('Please select a checkbox');
            }
        });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: U can push id's checked rows into the list send it to back-end.and delete that record from the data table.

Answer (score 1):

To remove each row from the datatable do the following in the each loop:

```
$('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

For the server side you will need ajax, get all the ids of the checked elements in a array pass them to a php via ajax and then do a select in array query and delete them

Comment: This code is deleting data from database whichever checkbox is selected

Comment: @Ruchirshah then use a different selector to select only the elements you want to delete,without the html i can't tell you what selector to chose

Answer (score 0):

I feel the best way is to collect all checked id's into an array by

```
var idsToDelete=[];$('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
                selectedid = $(this).val();idsToDelete.push(selectedID);
            });
```

Then send idsToDelete array to server/DB service and remove by Id. then again fetch new record and bind new list in html.
so no need to remove explicitly in html.

if you remove from first html, it may so happen that DB it doesn't reflect but UI removed. so better first remove from dB.

Comment: why do the extra jobs? when you can remove them using `remove`

Comment: @madalinivascu it's not about only removing UI, but from backend as well.

Comment: if you first removed from UI, but for some reason backend failed , what you will do in that case. hope you understood the idea.

Comment: usually when you program something like this you return the status of what the query produced , if there was an error in the execution of the query then you return a simple message not return/rebuild the whole table

Comment: what about UI which you have already removed before sending and waiting for success response? do you think your suggestion will be user friendly.

Comment: usually you do the removing from the page after the ajax is complete

Comment: my logic is even suggested by one more comment from @dipakthoke

Comment: ofcourse, that is why loading concept is there right? not me it is generic solution.